# Not calling didBecomeActive if background task expires

Tags: ios, background-process

Here is the situation:

I am picking a large video using imagepicker. Obviously the picker will take a bit of time to compress the video. So to ease user experience I have enabled background task for it.

Now here comes the issue:

If user choose a video and and tap the home button, application goes to background and continue compressing video for next 600 secs. And the background task expires. In the expiration handler I have stopped my background task.

Now if the user is resuming app after the background expiration

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

is not being invoked. Can anyone explain me why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

When the background tasks expires, your app will really be closed! So it's not becoming active again, it's launching.

You should handle stuff in your expiration handler or/and when your background task ends successfully. **Both situations**, you need to set the background_task as **invalidated**.

If your app goes to background while converting the video, and then user open it again BEFORE the task end or the background task expires, then you should see the app calling applicationDidBecomeActive.

I assume you know it, but maybe you are missing the multitask properties in your Info.plist file, so your app isn't accepting background tasks the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication)application

This method Only called when the app's sate is changed from inactive state to active state.
 Is it possible to know whether video picking finished? if it's possible then just store it. and when the user comes again to the app. just fire the functionality you required.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But I know this. I need to know why that method is not called even after app receives user integration. Thanks.

Comment: *integration = interaction

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add log statement to method `applicationDidFinishLaunching`? May be the app terminates or crashes before a user opens it.

Also, I think correct way is to save current parsing context when app receives signal like `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and when app starts resume parsing. Because a user can close the app manually.